# How do I use an interface in place of an any type param in a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

In typescript, react & redux, the `state` param of the `mapStateToProps` function connect method is declared as `any`.

```
interface MapStateToProps<TStateProps, TOwnProps> {
    (state: any, ownProps: TOwnProps): TStateProps;
}
```

I would like to use a type I have defined in my code in place of the any type for the state param. How can I achieve that ?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: MyStateInterface) => {};
```

But this does not work, as it does not match the signature.

What works is only if I put it like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {};
```

But then I loose my IDE autocompletion and type checking inside my function.

In fact it is more a typescript question than a redux one.

When a function type has a parameter with an `any` param, how do you specify the actual type of the parameter when you use it?

Comment: shouldn't it be `const mapStateToProps: MyStateInterface = (state) =>`? you are trying to assign the function value to the state param which isn't right. You could define a state interface that has the return values of your reducers if you want to assign that type to the state parameter

Comment: in fact I need to type the `state` param of the function.
the `MyStateInterface` is an interface that describes my store in the app (it could by name `StoreInterface`, I named it like this here to match the redux interface declaration)

Comment: Not really sure what you mean? if you have a index where you `combineReducers` you can define a type/interface for that combined reducer which is what the state value would be. let me write an answer to help explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a few reducers that do some stuff and then you are combining them to have some specific output like so

```
export default combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
    something: someReducer
});
```

where `userReducer` is this

```
interface UserReducerState {
    authenticated: boolean;
    loading: boolean;
    username: string;
    email: string;
}
const defaultState = {
    authenticated: false,
    loading: false,
    username: '',
    email: ''
};

export default (state: UserReducerState = defaultState, action: MyActionTypeInterface) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_LOADED:
            return {...state, ...action.payload, ...{authenticated: true, loading: false};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

when you `connect` a component the `mapStateToProps` function will receive a state argument that has the reducers values inside it

```
interface ConnectStateProps {
    user: UserReducerState;
    something: SomethingReducerState
}
const mapStateToProps = (state: ConnectStateProps) => {
    console.log(state);
    ...etc
```

the output of this console.log would look like this

```
{
    user: {
        authenticated: false,
        loading: false,
        username: '',
        email: ''
    },
    something: ...etc
}
```

Comment: yes exactly ; my problem is when I write `ConnectStateProps` as the type for the `state` param of the `mapStateToProps` function (like in your example), typescript tells me it does not match the function signature and expects the param type to be `any`; like this for your example `const mapStateToProps = (state: any)`

Comment: @Bouni can you create a jsfiddle for this? I use this exact thing right now. Not much I can do to help with the current information

Comment: I have found my mistake, as you said earlues it was in the return type that did not match not the type of the param. I have misread the typescript compiler error message